# Reverse user input

Tags: hello-world

This is a pretty simple one. if the user enters "Hello World" your code should output "dlroW olleH"

I was inspired by the multiplication question recently posted. I know this is probably easy in bash.

As this is code-golf, least bytes wins.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 13 bytes

```
StringReverse
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zgq/A/uKQoMy89KLUstag49X8AkFOi4JAWreSRmpOTrxCeX5STohT7HwA)